# What is an efficient way to sort a graph?

Tags: c++, sorting, graph

For example suppose there are 3 nodes A,B,C and A links to B and C, B links to A and C, and C links to B and A. In visual form its like this

```
C <- A -> B //A links to B & C
A <- B -> C //B links to A & C
B <- C -> A //C links to B & A
```

Assume the A,B,C are held in an array like so [A,B,C] with index starting at 0. How can I efficiently sort the array [A,B,C] according to the value held by each node.

For example if A holds 4, B holds -2 and C holds -1, then sortGraph([A,B,C]) should return [B,C,A]. Hope its clear. Would it be possible if I can somehow utilize std::sort?

EDIT: Not basic sort algorithm. Let me clarify a bit more. Assume I have a list of Nodes [n0,n1...nm]. Each ni has a left and right neighbor index. For example, n1 left neight is n0 and its right neighbor is n2. I use index to represent the neighbor. If n1 is at index 1, then its left neighbor is at index 0 and its right neighbor is at index 2. If I sort the array, then I need to update the neighbor index as well. I don't want to really implement my own sorting algorithm, any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: isnt what you are asking just basic sorting? i.e nothing to do with graphs..

Comment: Is this homework?  [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: just did a re-edit to explain a little bit more

Comment: are you saying `ni` is connected to `n(i-1)` and `n(i+1)`? That is kinda messy. I dont think u can sort that. Change your node to have pointers to Left and Right, and your original array is a list of pointers to these nodes, and then it becomes trivial

Comment: If on the other hand you mean that each node keeps track of left index and right index, it would still be fixed by using pointers to nodes instead of indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the edited question correctly your graph is a **circular linked list**: each node points to the previous and next nodes, and the "last" node points to the "first" node as its next node.

There's nothing particularly special you need to do the sort that you want.  Here are the basic steps I'd use.

1. Put all the nodes into an array.
2. Sort the array using any sorting algorithm (e.g. [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)).
3. Loop through the result and reset the prev/next pointers for each node, taking into account the special cases for the first and last node.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C++ implementation, hope is useful (it includes several algorithms like dijkstra, kruskal, for sorting it uses depth first search, etc...)

Graph.h

```
#ifndef __GRAPH_H
#define __GRAPH_H

#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <set>

typedef struct __edge_t
{
    int v0, v1, w;

    __edge_t():v0(-1),v1(-1),w(-1){}
    __edge_t(int from, int to, int weight):v0(from),v1(to),w(weight){}
} edge_t;

class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(void); // construct a graph with no vertex (and thus no edge)
    Graph(int n); // construct a graph with n-vertex, but no edge
    Graph(const Graph &graph); // deep copy of a graph, avoid if not necessary
public:
    // @destructor
    virtual ~Graph(void);
public:
    inline int getVertexCount(void) const { return this->numV; }
    inline int getEdgeCount(void)   const { return this->numE; }
public:
    // add an edge
    // @param: from [in] - starting point of the edge
    // @param: to   [in] - finishing point of the edge
    // @param: weight[in] - edge weight, only allow positive values
    void addEdge(int from, int to, int weight=1);
    // get all edges
    // @param: edgeList[out] - an array with sufficient size to store the edges
    void getAllEdges(edge_t edgeList[]);
public:
    // topological sort
    // @param: vertexList[out] - vertex order
    void sort(int vertexList[]);
    // dijkstra's shortest path algorithm
    // @param: v[in] - starting vertex
    // @param: path[out] - an array of <distance, prev> pair for each vertex
    void dijkstra(int v, std::pair<int, int> path[]);
    // kruskal's minimum spanning tree algorithm
    // @param: graph[out] - the minimum spanning tree result
    void kruskal(Graph &graph);
    // floyd-warshall shortest distance algorithm
    // @param: path[out] - a matrix of <distance, next> pair in C-style
    void floydWarshall(std::pair<int, int> path[]);
private:
    // resursive depth first search
    void sort(int v, std::pair<int, int> timestamp[], std::stack<int> &order);
    // find which set the vertex is in, used in kruskal
    std::set<int>* findSet(int v, std::set<int> vertexSet[], int n);
    // union two sets, used in kruskal
    void setUnion(std::set<int>* s0, std::set<int>* s1);
    // initialize this graph
    void init(int n);
    // initialize this graph by copying another
    void init(const Graph &graph);
private:
    int numV, numE; // number of vertices and edges
    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >* adjList; // adjacency list
};

#endif
```

Graph.cpp

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

Graph::Graph()
:numV(0), numE(0), adjList(0)
{
}

Graph::Graph(int n)
:numV(0), numE(0), adjList(0)
{
    this->init(n);
}

Graph::Graph(const Graph &graph)
:numV(0), numE(0), adjList(0)
{
    this->init(graph);
}

Graph::~Graph()
{
    delete[] this->adjList;
}

void Graph::init(int n)
{
    if(this->adjList){
        delete[] this->adjList;
    }
    this->numV = n;
    this->numE = 0;
    this->adjList = new std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >[n];
}

void Graph::init(const Graph &graph)
{
    this->init(graph.numV);    
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        this->adjList[i] = graph.adjList[i];
    }
}

void Graph::addEdge(int from, int to, int weight)
{
    if(weight > 0){
        this->adjList[from].push_back( std::make_pair(to, weight) );
        this->numE++;
    }
}

void Graph::getAllEdges(edge_t edgeList[])
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < this->adjList[i].size(); j++){
            // add this edge to edgeList
            edgeList[k++] = edge_t(i, this->adjList[i][j].first, this->adjList[i][j].second);
        }
    }
}

void Graph::sort(int vertexList[])
{
    std::pair<int, int>* timestamp = new std::pair<int, int>[this->numV];
    std::stack<int> order;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->numV; i++){
        timestamp[i].first = -1;
        timestamp[i].second = -1;
    }

    for(int v = 0; v < this->numV; v++){
        if(timestamp[v].first < 0){
            this->sort(v, timestamp, order);
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    while(!order.empty()){
        vertexList[i++] = order.top();
        order.pop();
    }
    delete[] timestamp;
    return;
}

void Graph::sort(int v, std::pair<int, int> timestamp[], std::stack<int> &order)
{
    // discover vertex v
    timestamp[v].first = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->adjList[v].size(); i++){
        int next = this->adjList[v][i].first;
        if(timestamp[next].first < 0){
            this->sort(next, timestamp, order);
        }
    }
    // finish vertex v
    timestamp[v].second = 1;
    order.push(v);
    return;
}

void Graph::dijkstra(int v, std::pair<int, int> path[])
{
    int* q = new int[numV];
    int numQ = numV;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->numV; i++){
        path[i].first = -1; // infinity distance
        path[i].second = -1; // no path exists
        q[i] = i;
    }

    // instant reachable to itself
    path[v].first = 0;
    path[v].second = -1;

    while(numQ > 0){
        int u = -1; // such node not exists
        for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
            if(q[i] >= 0 
            && path[i].first >= 0 
            && (u < 0 || path[i].first < path[u].first)){ // 
                u = i;
            }
        }


        if(u == -1){
            // all remaining nodes are unreachible
            break;
        }
        // remove u from Q
        q[u] = -1;
        numQ--;

        for(int i = 0; i < this->adjList[u].size(); i++){
            std::pair<int, int>& edge = this->adjList[u][i];
            int alt = path[u].first + edge.second;

            if(path[edge.first].first < 0 || alt < path[ edge.first ].first){
                path[ edge.first ].first = alt;
                path[ edge.first ].second = u;
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] q;
    return;
}

// compare two edges by their weight
bool edgeCmp(edge_t e0, edge_t e1)
{
    return e0.w < e1.w;
}

std::set<int>* Graph::findSet(int v, std::set<int> vertexSet[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(vertexSet[i].find(v) != vertexSet[i].end()){
            return vertexSet+i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Graph::setUnion(std::set<int>* s0, std::set<int>* s1)
{
    if(s1->size() > s0->size()){
        std::set<int>* temp = s0;
        s0 = s1;
        s1 = temp;
    }

    for(std::set<int>::iterator i = s1->begin(); i != s1->end(); i++){
        s0->insert(*i);
    }
    s1->clear();
    return;
}

void Graph::kruskal(Graph &graph)
{
    std::vector<edge_t> edgeList;
    edgeList.reserve(numE);
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < this->adjList[i].size(); j++){
            // add this edge to edgeList
            edgeList.push_back( edge_t(i, this->adjList[i][j].first, this->adjList[i][j].second) );
        }
    }

    // sort the list in ascending order
    std::sort(edgeList.begin(), edgeList.end(), edgeCmp);

    graph.init(numV);   
    // create disjoint set of the spanning tree constructed so far
    std::set<int>* disjoint = new std::set<int>[this->numV];
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        disjoint[i].insert(i);
    }

    for(int e = 0; e < edgeList.size(); e++){
        // consider edgeList[e]
        std::set<int>* s0 = this->findSet(edgeList[e].v0, disjoint, numV);
        std::set<int>* s1 = this->findSet(edgeList[e].v1, disjoint, numV);
        if(s0 == s1){
            // adding this edge will make a cycle
            continue;
        }

        // add this edge to MST
        graph.addEdge(edgeList[e].v0, edgeList[e].v1, edgeList[e].w);
        // union s0 & s1
        this->setUnion(s0, s1);
    }
    delete[] disjoint;
    return;
}

#define IDX(i,j)    ((i)*numV+(j))

void Graph::floydWarshall(std::pair<int, int> path[])
{
    // initialize
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numV; j++){
            path[IDX(i,j)].first = -1;
            path[IDX(i,j)].second = -1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < this->adjList[i].size(); j++){
            path[IDX(i,this->adjList[i][j].first)].first
                = this->adjList[i][j].second;
            path[IDX(i,this->adjList[i][j].first)].second
                = this->adjList[i][j].first;
        }
    }

    // dynamic programming
    for(int k = 0; k < numV; k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numV; j++){
                if(path[IDX(i,k)].first == -1
                || path[IDX(k,j)].first == -1){
                    // no path exist from i-to-k or from k-to-j
                    continue;
                }

                if(path[IDX(i,j)].first == -1
                || path[IDX(i,j)].first > path[IDX(i,k)].first + path[IDX(k,j)].first){
                    // there is a shorter path from i-to-k, and from k-to-j
                    path[IDX(i,j)].first = path[IDX(i,k)].first + path[IDX(k,j)].first;
                    path[IDX(i,j)].second = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for sorting algorithms you should just ask google:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

My personal favourite is the BogoSort coupled with parallel universe theory. The theory is that if you hook a machine up to the program that can destroy the universe, then if the list isn't sorted after one iteration it will destroy the universe. That way all the parallel universes except the one with the list sorted will be destroyed and you have a sorting algorithm with complexity O(1).

The best ....

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct like this:

```
template<typename Container, typename Comparison = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
struct SortHelper
{
    Container const* container;
    size_t org_index;
    SortHelper( Container const* c, size_t index ):container(c), org_index(index) {}
    bool operator<( SortHelper other ) const
    {
      return Comparison()( (*c)[org_index], (*other.c)[other.org_index] );
    }
};
```

This lets you resort things however you want.

Now, make a `std::vector<SortHelper<blah>>`, sort it, and you now have a `vector` of instructions of where everything ends up going after you sort it.

Apply these instructions (there are a few ways).  An easy way would be to reuse `container` pointer as a bool.  Walk the sorted `vector` of helpers.  Move the first entry to where it should go, moving what you found where it should go to where it should go, and repeat until you loop or the entire array is sorted.  As you go, clear the `container` pointers in your helper struct, and check them to make sure you don't move an entry that has already been moved (this lets you detect loops, for example).

Once a loop has occurred, proceed down the `vector` looking for the next as-yet-not-in-right-place entry (with a non-null `container` pointer).